# C# - SQL Database - Sending query to update records however too many update requests cause some to get missed

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, updates

I've searched high and lo, so apologies if I have missed something.

When I run the source, no errors arise and it looks as if everything is working as it should, however when I inspect the database, only some records have been updated/added and others have been missed.

The rate of updates currently varies between 1 per second to an upwards of 25 per second (some headroom/just incase, but typically around 15).

In this section, I query the database to pull existing values, make my adjustments on those values, then save it back to the database.

Below is the snippet that updates the SQL database, there are about **43 columns** being updated (some may remain the same value, but they are being re-added).

Is there any way I can ensure all update requests pass through and succeed in updating?

```
try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
    connection.Open();
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE user_information SET exampleValue = @exampleValue WHERE username = @username";
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exampleValue", exampleValue);

    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Close();
        //this.LoadData();
    }
}
```

Comment: @X-TECH is saying the where clause is missing records due to space padding. `'__Smith___'` (under scores represent spaces) does not equal `'Smith'` Also check to see if the collation of the database is case-sensitive.  If so 'Smith' does not equal 'smith'.

Comment: When you inspect the database, are you looking at anything else that indicates that an effort to add or update a record was unsuccessful?

Comment: Hey all, I understand I haven't provided the full source where the arguments come in (username for example). Username has already been fixed, so I can verify that is not the issue. -- To add some more insight, along with this code above, I log everything in a separate table - that portion of the code adds a new row into the a different table, and it adds the username, message, and time. That is being updated at the same rate and that is just a straight INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better comparison, use [LTRIM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) & [RTRIM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) i-e `LTRIM(RTRIM(username))` in `SQL` and in `C#` use [String.Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) i-e `usename.Trim()`

`LTRIM(RTRIM(username))` will remove extra spaces of username in database eg. '     Smith ' -> 'Smith' and `username.Trim()` remove spaces of your input

So your replace the lines

```
cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE user_information SET exampleValue = @exampleValue WHERE username = @username";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
```

with

```
cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE user_information SET exampleValue = @exampleValue WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(username)) = @username";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Trim());
```

To avoid case sensitive comparison, use [LOWER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400(v=sql.105).aspx) i-e `LOWER(username)` in `SQL` and in `C#` use [String.ToLower()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx), so `username.ToLower()`

Now, code will be like that

```
cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE user_information SET exampleValue = @exampleValue WHERE LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(username))) = @username";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Trim().ToLower());
```

Comment: I'll throw this update in and see what changes occur

Comment: Added the changes you have suggestion, and I believe the SQL query portion for the username has changed. I have also noticed that the slowness is not directly the SQL but rather the amount of information coming in (data source is IRC) and it actually gets further and further behind due to the chat being faster than what my set up processes. - In regards to SQL Query and accuracy, your suggestion will definitely ensure no issues arise regarding that. Thanks!  (tidbit, the entry I put in to see if it updated too about 10 minutes from IRC entry to it flowing to my system then to DB... IRC issue)

Answer (score 1):

Base on your snippet, there's no wrong thing the way you update the data. But one thing i observed is the way you pass the parameter. In that case you did not specify the datatype of your parameter. so i assume that the '@username' and '@exampleValue' is string.

In some ways , if the datatype of your column in your table did not match to the datatype of your parameter. it may cause to fail the update of the data.

It is better if you can provide us the structure of your table to evaluate further your problem.

Regards.